# Div width 100% but there is still space on the sides

Tags: html, css, spacing

I am trying to make the background of my code have a picture that is 300px in height and 100% in width, but when I set the width to 100%, it doesn't go all the way, there are about 15px areas between each side. I understand I could just set the width to something like 1000px, but that has a lot of issues with it; such as that might look good on some monitors with different sizes. I have asked a question like this before but it had a few different aspects. It got answered, but I can not use that solution to answer this question.
[JSfiddle](http://%3Cdiv%20id='header'%3E%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src='http://i.imgur.com/tvTMm.jpg'%20id='headerbg'%3E%20%3C/div%3E)

HTML:

```
<div id='header'>
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/tvTMm.jpg' id='headerbg'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerbg {
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/tvTMm.jpg');
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  background-repeat:none;
  background-size:1340px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: fiddle link not working

Comment: please show the style of `#header`. Do you have any padding for `#header`?

Comment: Open the page in Chromium, right click on the image and select "inspect element". Down at the bottom, there is an image showing padding, spacing etc. Adjust the style until the extra space goes away and then apply what you found to the original source. Firefox+Firebug and Opera also work but the display may be different.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this CSS to remove the spaces

**CSS**

```
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
```

}

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qrxbya1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/g3bwfx6y/
There is no extra space.

Is the extra space the default `margin` for `body` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the padding, and

```
body, html {
     margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

generally doesn't work because the CSS of the Padding from your 'more specific' selection, will take priority.
Something like:

```
menu li {
     padding: 10px;
}
```

would take priority.
So, you should sort out the code from it's own specific line. Or use the "!" important marker.

```
body, html {
     margin: 0!; padding: 0!;
}
```

Would take priority over:

```
 menu li {
     padding: 10px;
}
```